# What is the naming convention for class that contains data of static nature?

Tags: oop, naming-conventions

> Static is data that doesn't change. Dynamic is data that does change.
>
> Consider a company that keeps track of its customers. It keeps a list
>   of those customers in a certain spot. That's dynamic data - it changes
>   all the time, as customers are added, deleted, and updated. But, on
>   each customer form, there's a spot where you can pick what industry
>   they're in - Agriculture, Financial, Automotive, etc. The options
>   AVAILABLE in that list are considered static data.

Is there a good naming convention for static data?

Comment: Naming conventions exist per language and framework, and even per project; not per concept.

Comment: A constant enumeration?